# How to remove certain characters from a string and break them down

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a tuple that I received after getting some data from an SQLite3 database and it looks like this (‘1’, ‘dextron’). How would I remove the brackets and add dextron to a string

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck ?

Comment: I tried to put it into a list then join it But it didn’t work

Comment: add the code you tried please.

Comment: I was playing around with it a little and tried using it how id use a list and it worked

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of fiddling around i got it to work.

```
info = ("1','dextron')
user = info[1]
print(user)
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it in python or not id like to hear any better ideas or imporvements